# Why affected rows return 0 while update/delete success?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have statements:

```
INSERT INTO infotbl(name, phone) VALUES('Alex', '9999999');
```

**and update it:**

```
UPDATE infotbl SET name = 'Alex Johnes', phone = '999 34356063' WHERE id = 1;
```

**then delete:**

```
DELETE FROM infotbl WHERE id = 1;
```

I've inserted successfully, when I update and delete rows has been change in MySQL. but my code in Node return affected rows = 0. Why?. There is my function to update and delete in Node:

```
function deleteCustomer (id, callback) {
        db.connection.query("DELETE FROM infotbl WHERE id=?", id, (err, result) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (result.affectedRows > 0)
                callback(true);
            else
                callback(false);
        });
    };
```

**and update function:**

```
function updateCustomer(id, name, phone, callback) {
    db.connection.query("UPDATE infotbl SET name = ?, phone = ? WHERE id = ?;", [name, phone, id], (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
                if (result.affectedRows > 0)
                    callback(true);
                else
                    callback(false);
});
}
```

Why node return 0 affected rows when database executed successfully?

Comment: Try consoling the `result` object. It might be that the db driver you are using got updated and it may be returning `affectedRows` by some different property name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that there are no rows that satisfy the conditions in the UPDATE and DELETE statements.  That is, there are no rows with `id` value equal to `1`.

An UPDATE could affect zero rows if the conditions match one or more rows, but the changes applied to the row result in "no change"... that is, the columns being modified already have the values being assigned.

An UPDATE or DELETE that executes successfully, but affects zero rows, is still   considered successful.